# Replace characters in a string ( along with which exists in array )

Tags: php, str-replace

I need to replace certain characters.

```
$to_replace = array( "{username}", "{email}" );
$replace_with = array( $username, $email );
```

Also, `$key_value` is an array which gives me array key and values like:

```
array(
  'site' => 'abc.com',
  'blog' => 'blog.com'
  'roll' => 42
);
```

Using

```
$message = 'This is a {username} speaking, my email is {email}, and my site is {site} with roll {roll}';

$message = str_replace( $to_replace, $replace_with, $message );
```

This way I can replace username and email, How can I make it to site, blog and roll?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following solution:

```
$email = 'johndoe@example.com';
$username = 'johndoe';

$to_replace = array( "{username}", "{email}" );
$replace_with = array( $username, $email );

$key_value = array(
    'site' => 'abc.com',
    'blog' => 'blog.com',
    'roll' => 42
);

//add the keys and values from $key_value to the replacement arrays.
$to_replace = array_merge($to_replace, array_keys($key_value));
$replace_with = array_merge($replace_with, array_values($key_value));

//surround every key with { and }.
array_walk($to_replace, function(&$value, $key) { $value = '{'.trim($value, '{}').'}';});

$message = 'This is a {username} speaking, my email is {email}, and my site is {site} with roll {roll}';
$message = str_replace( $to_replace, $replace_with, $message );

var_dump($message); //This is a johndoe speaking, my email is johndoe@example.com, and my site is abc.com with roll 42
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/isN90N

Answer (score 1):

It would be so much easier to just populate the first two arrays with all of the data you want to replace, but if your stuck with what you have so far, then this will do the job.

This takes the keys of the last array (using `array_keys()`) and adds {} round it using `array_walk()`.  And the array values and merges both these into the original arrays.

```
$to_replace = array( "{username}", "{email}" );
$replace_with = array( $username, $email );

$extra = array(
    'site' => 'abc.com',
    'blog' => 'blog.com',
  'roll' => 42
);

$extraTo = array_keys($extra);
array_walk($extraTo, function(&$d) { $d= "{".$d."}";});
$to_replace = array_merge($to_replace, $extraTo);
$replace_with = array_merge($replace_with, array_values($extra));

$message = 'This is a {username} speaking, my email is {email}, and my site is {site} with roll {roll}';
$message = str_replace( $to_replace, $replace_with, $message );

echo $message;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [extract](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) function to achieve this in easiest possible way.

And, try to wrap the message logic in a separate function for sanitising data and avoiding variable name conflicts.

```
function createMessage($username, $email, $userMeta) {
    extract($userMeta);
    return "This is a {$username} speaking, my email is {$email}, and my site is {$site} with roll {$roll}";
}

$username = 'awesome';
$email = 'email@email.com';
$userMeta = array(
    'site' => 'abc.com',
    'blog' => 'blog.com',
    'roll' => 42
);

echo createMessage($username, $email, $userMeta);
// This is a awesome speaking, my email is email@email.com, and my site is abc.com with roll 42
```

Warning: Do not use extract() on untrusted data, like user input (e.g. $_GET, $_FILES).